# Dynamically change image source in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am using Flask to make a small face detection app. I want to achieve when faces are detected, they will be updated in the HTML page.

In javascript part, I am using getUserMedia to stream camera images from the client to a server.

In Flask part, I receive images and process them using this function:

```
@app.route('/image.jpeg', methods=['POST'])
def on_image_captured():
    data = request.data
    image_file = request.files['image']
    image = Image.open(image_file)
    image = np.array(image)
    image = image[..., :3]
    # faces is a list of detected faces (a list of numpy array)
    faces = system.detect_faces(image)
    return ''
```

My HTML has two things to render: first one is the streamed video, the other is the detected faces. My question is, how do I send the detected faces (the `faces` variable) to HTML so that it will render variable numbers of faces on the page dynamically?

Comment: Do you want to send back the detected images, or just the data points generated by the face detection function. (how would you display them?)

Comment: I would like to send back the detected images and display them inside the HTML page.

Comment: All of them or only the most recent?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in multiple ways .
Probably the easiest method ( but with the most lag ) is to send back the image with a square around their face. You can use opencv drawing fuctions to do that easily in python.

Alternatively you can send back a json object and then use the metadata in the client side. look at flask jsonify. You will need some function on the js side with intervals to fetch the json. This may be hard to synchronize.

You can also use tensorflow.js to perform the face detection on the client side to avoid the synchronization.